# 32bit XImage, XPutImage and alpha blending

Tags: linux, xlib

## The setting

Using XLib, I am creating 32 bit-per-pixel window and also 32 bpp XImage object.

At first I am drawing opaque rectangle on the window in order to erase the background.

Then I try to draw the created semi-transparent XImage on the window.

On these operations I can use only GXCopy function of the graphic context, because all other functions behave not good with the alpha channel.

But, drawing the XImage, it does not blend with the background, but simply replace it (GXCopy) this way, creating transparent holes in the window.

## The question

**Is there a way to make the X server to properly blend semi-transparent images?** 
(Maybe some function named GXBlend?)

P.S. I am aware of XRender extensions, but prefer to use XLib if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's why XRender was introduced. Another option is GLX. One more option (slow): transfer previous content to client, blend in your client code and put pixmap back to server.

Comment: Hm, but I don't need transparent windows, I need only transparent images on my window. Then I can just draw the whole window content on the client side and only XPutImage to the server. Do you think this will be slow as well?

Comment: You asked about server-side compositing, and the answer is "not with core x11". Yes, you can do it client side and XPutImage result

Comment: Indeed, I asked about the server-side compositing. The comments are just comments... ;)